# Double Parameter URL Rewrite

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have the following URL with double parameters and for the first time would like to do double parameter rewrite.

My URL: `http://localhost/b2b/post?post_id=1&post_subject=test`

I'd like to rewrite it to: `http://localhost/b2b/post/post_id/1/post_subject/test`

My .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<Files ~ "^(.*)\.(inc|tpl|sql)$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just write :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^post/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)$  /post.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry to say, just didnt work... thanks anyway.. please help could it be a REQUEST URI or REQUEST QUERY Needed?

Comment: In which folder is located your .htaccess ? localhost ? b2b ? post ?
Does the rewriting work for one parameter ? 
In my opinion, your .htaccess is a mess. You should read this page : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/